# How can I convert an account of type sp_runtime::traits::IdentifyAccount::AccountId to sp_runtime::AccountId32?

Tags: config, accountid, traits, multiaddress

I get the following error when trying to convert my `frame_system::Config::AccountId` to a `MultiAddress`.

```rs
expected enum `MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>`
   found enum `MultiAddress<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, _>`
consider constraining the associated type `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId` to `sp_runtime::AccountId32`
```

Here is the code that fails to create a `MultiAddress` from the `AccountId`.

```rs
Self::ensure_pallet_enabled()?;

let staker = ensure_signed(origin)?;

let location: MultiLocation = MultiLocation {
    parents: 1,
    interior: Here,
};

let create_nomination_pool =
                RuntimeCall::NominationPools(pallet_nomination_pools::Call::<
                    polkadot_runtime::Runtime,
                >::create {
                    amount: 10000,
                    root: MultiAddress::from(staker),
                    nominator: MultiAddress::from(staker),
                    bouncer: MultiAddress::from(staker),
                });
```

Here is the type of my `frame_system::Config::AccountId`.

```rs
pub type AccountId = <<Signature as sp_runtime::traits::Verify>::Signer as sp_runtime::traits::IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a trait to do this.

```rs
#[pallet::config]
trait Config: frame_system::Config {
  AccountIdConvertor: AccountIdConvertor<Self::AccountId>;
}

trait AccountIdConvertor<A> {
  fn to_32(a: A) -> AccountId32;
}

#[pallet::call]
fn c(origin: OriginFor<T>) {
  let a = ensure_signed(origin)?;
  let a_32 = T::AccountIdConvertor::to_u32(a);

  ..
}
```

Or you can limit only accountid32 chain can use this pallet.

```rs
#[pallet::config]
trait Config: frame_system::Config<AccountId = AccountId32> {}

..
```

Comment: Won't I need to implement the `AccountIdConverter::to_32` method for the `frame_system::Config::AccountId`?

Comment: Nope, you should define a struct at runtime level, and implement this trait for it. Finally, pass this struct to the `youpallet::Config::AccountIdConvertor`.

Comment: Is there a public implementation of `AccountIdConverter` that we can look for reference?